# Why i am getting extra values from variable scope function?

Tags: php, variables

Can anyone explain why i am getting this output with the following script

Output

1first
2first
3first
4first
5first
6first
7first
8first
9first
10first
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

```
function test() {
static $count = 0;
$count++;
echo $count."first";
echo "<br>";
if ($count < 10) {
    test();
}
echo $count--;
echo "<br>";
return $count."a"; }
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do with this one?

Comment: you have one echo and one return

Comment: You get this output because that's how the function operates. What do you expect instead?

Comment: exactly your code is working like this so you got this output!!!

Comment: Why i am getting the result as 10 9 8 7 6 like that

Comment: Please explain the function execution process

Answer (score 0):

Ten times case is too complicated for explanation. In the three times case, it is more easy

```
1st test() => $count++; show '1first'; call next test();
2nd   test() => $count++; show '2first'; call next test()
3rd     test() => $count++; show '3first' $count--; show '3'; return
4th   $count--; show '2'; return
5th $count--; show '1'; return
```

Edit:

```
          call           call
test()  1  ->  test() 2  ->  test() 3
        1  <-         2  <-         3
          return        return
```

or

```
 test() 
 echo ++$count
 call ---------------> test() 
                       echo ++$count
                       call ---------------> test()
                                             echo ++$count
                                             echo $count--
                       echo $count-- <------ return
 echo $count-- <------ return
 return
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Okay make it for 3 times
My question is that the "test" function executes 3 times only until count reaches 3, so for that 1first, 2first are executing.
But why count-- will exectute 3 times and gives output as 3, 2 and 1?

Comment: At the last last loop, if condition is false, therefore the code after 'if statement' is performed. And return back to the last-1 loop in which the code after 'if statement' is performed again.

Comment: Sorry i think i am disturbing you. But i am not understanding properly.
First section is Okay but why i am getting count-- repeating three times?

Comment: as per my knowledge i understood the output shold be like below
1first
2first
3first

Now the if condition becomes false so the out of the "If condition" code will be executed i.e. count--

So output should be

2

Comment: When $count = 3, 'echo $count--' shows 3. After showing, $count becomes 2.

Answer (score 0):

Another explanation how functions run in stack environment

First in Last out

**I will just comment test values on run mode for count < 3**

```
// - First Call -
static $count = 0;
$count++; // count 1
echo $count."first"; // echo count 1first
echo "<br>"; 
if ($count < 3) {
    test();
}

// - Second Call -
static $count = 0; // ignore
$count++; // count 2
echo $count."first"; // echo count 2first
echo "<br>"; 
if ($count < 3) {
    test();
}

// - Third Call -
static $count = 0; // ignore
$count++; // count 3
echo $count."first"; // echo count 3first
echo "<br>"; 
if ($count < 3) {
    test(); // no more calling so we can continue to stack
}

// - Third Call Continues-
echo $count--; // echo count 3, count is now 2 
echo "<br>";
return $count."a";

// - Second Call Continues-
echo $count--; // echo count 2, count is now 1
echo "<br>";
return $count."a";

// - First Call Continues-
echo $count--; // echo count 1, count is now 0
echo "<br>";
return $count."a";
```